# Need help on Generic extend string purpose

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Hi need help to understand following typescript

1. Generic `K extends string`
2. If K is restricted to string type then how can we iterate using `key in K`

   ```
   type NewMappedTypes<K extends string> = { [key in K]: boolean } // 1
   //2. if Generic is restricted to string type then how can we iterate over keys
   function composeTypedMap<K extends string>(k: NewMappedTypes<K>) {
       return k;
   }

   const t = composeTypedMap({ 'a': true ,'b':false});
   console.log(t)
   ```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAguE8AcFMAIDloHcCyBDSMAmAVK0BnAHgGlZoAPUaAOywNgNACcBLGgcwD5YBeWAN6wA2gGto4WO1gkAugC5YAIwD2KgDbQ0NWAF8QAMwCuNAMahWKnaZUBbSCoLQ82dJFLkqteoxbtuABSiioioGNguhKRcAJSCwLCJsMzQoEbMOqIA3MD6wDY0TLCgfLA29o7O%20FhuAUIA5Gj1iixGcAA09UrNBmjqTroxOQUEGtAAdOoqHAGgMUA)

Comment: `K` can be a union of strings. After all, a union of strings extends `string`. You don't "iterate" over `K`. You map each constituent of the union `K` to `boolean` in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`K extends string` is a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints). You're right in thinking that `K` must be *assignable to* `string`.

However (while the syntax doesn't make it obvious) it doesn't mean just "one" string can be used for `K`: you can supply a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), which will be used in the [type mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) operation of that type utility.

Here's another example to help clarify what's happening:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAEFkEMAcGdQC4AsCmoC2L0CMUCd4AKAYwHsA7WBASwQFcVyFYBKUUgM0VVCr2vIBzUHXLUKiUqADWKAJ7wB3NKWwArFMQQAuAFAI50NAGUE-IQFUxFACqkA0vNgBJcgHl1mhG44AhUqQANiiQ5ABqkIEMsAA8FqAoAB4IjAAm8HwCggB8oAC8oADeuqCgANqmeKBKFgC62qDYAcGhANy6AL7t+oZoAKKJkOjQwZVZADK0+JHwBQDkHAFzoAA+oHPYkHjLaxuQAF5z3QZGoANDIygeGlr5oGOW1uR2jgqu114+-kEh4ZHRMXOw1GZgmUzwM2y7VKoBAAD0APy6HqnD5aABieFI6AAUnQqA9hAVCVZxM8HE53p4tF9mr8IlEULFMkIoSVSvCkUA)

```ts
// Maps the members (constituents) of the string union to keys in the object:
type StringUnionToKeysInObjectOfBooleanValues<U extends string> = {
  [Str in U]: boolean;
};

type ExampleStringLiterals = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';

type ExampleObject = StringUnionToKeysInObjectOfBooleanValues<ExampleStringLiterals>;
   //^? Looks like:
/*

type ExampleObject = {
    foo: boolean;
    bar: boolean;
    baz: boolean;
}

*/

type ObjectFromJustString = StringUnionToKeysInObjectOfBooleanValues<string>;
   //^? Looks like:
/*

type ObjectFromJustString = {
    [x: string]: boolean;
}

*/
```

---

In the code you've shown, the compiler is using [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) to infer the types of the keys in the object literal that you provide as the argument to the function:

```ts
{ 'a': true ,'b':false}
```

They are inferred as the string union `"a" | "b"` and become the actual type used in place of the generic type parameter `K`.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73505591/need-help-on-generic-extend-string-purpose/73505738#comment129805487_73505738) @DarrylNoakes See update at the end of my question. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and much required help